# Passing objects from servlets to client side(javascript)

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp, servlets

I'd like to know what is the best way to pass data from servlet to js code.
The only solution that came up to my mind is to serialize object to json string, then pass it as an request attribute to jsp page and then get it in js code and deserialize.

Is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: Use spring mvc to write rest based services that return json to a javascript client in the browser, which then uses it to render the display.

Comment: you can ship raw JS instead of JSON if you want Dates, RegExps and methods...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate the JSON object into a `<script>` tag within the JSP syntax, so you have inline javascript that the browser will deserialize on page load without you needing to grab the request attribute. It would be something similar to the following within the JSP page.

```
...
<script>
<% 
out.println("myJSONObj = " + myJSONObject.toString()) 
%>
//other javascript stuff...
console.log(myJSONObj.key1);
</script>
...
```

So you rendered output/read in on the browser would be something like (the actual JSON object would be dependent on what you serialize -- put into your `JSONObject` of course):

```
...
<script>
myJSONObj = {key1:value1,array1:[val1,val2,val3]};
//other javascript stuff...
console.log(myJSONObj.key1);
</script>
...
```

Another option would be with AJAX to simple return the JSON string from the servlet and receive that with the return type being JSON (if using jquery ajax, otherwise JSON.parse(...) on the xhr response).

Comment: Thanks for the answer) I thought that ajax is used for making async  calls to server. And in my case I don't really need it. Am I right?

Comment: The direct generation of your object via JSP would generate the HTML and JS already containing the serialized object. Upon page load the browser would automatically load the object from the JS. This route has nothing to do with AJAX. I added the AJAX option in because the question was broad and wanted to outline the option. AJAX is for making async calls to the server -- It can be done synchronously as well. It is a good practice to abstract functionality away and to have a specific servlet instance (with proper parameter passing) to return JSON strings, especially in REST architecture.

Comment: Thank you, it's much clearer now)

Comment: Happy to have helped, best of luck with your code =]